# Perl determining if repeating value in string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a perl program that thru SNMP is pulling down values for memory to tell me if they are OK or not.  It will return 03 if the memory is good.  In the system memory amounts could vary but say in one I have a bank of 12 modules.  SNMP would return as a single string:

03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03

03 means it is OK.  Anything other than 03 is a problem.  Is there a simple way in Perl to parse thru what I would guess is a space separated list and if any contain anything other than 03 return an error or return OK?

Thanks.

JR

Comment: What MIB and OID are you using? There might be a more specific OID that doesn't require you to do your own parsing.

Comment: @stribizhev Fails for `02 02 02`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: You are right, the regex can be even simpler for this: `if ("03 03 03" !~ /^03(?: 03)*$/) {
 print "Bad!";
}`

Comment: ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I was hoping for this but I'm using Dell Command Monitor 9.1 which is a client based add-on that I am using to expose some readings from my devices.  There are a lot of Combined values, but in some cases there is no option for that.  Glad to get in more details if you think I'm truly barking down the wrong tree.  it should be noted that the OID's do exist.  When I use an MIB Browser, the individual value option is there, and the combined it also, but when I query some specific combined values it says NoSuchName.  This would be part of Dell's 10909.mib.

Comment: Should be noted when I walk the entire MIB I get a timeout at the same point each time saying %Failed to get value of SNMP variable. Variable does not exist (noSuchName(2))

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can split your string on whitespace and filter for values that are not `'03'`:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

my $SNMP_OK = '03';
sub valid { 
   my ($snmp_string) = @_;

   return ! grep { $_ ne $SNMP_OK } 
            split ' ', $snmp_string;
}

valid('03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03'); # True
valid('03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 02'); # False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $str = "03 03 03 03 03";
# replace all 03 
$str =~s/03//g;
# replace all space 
$str=~ s/ //g;
# str length >1 ,problem
```

Comment: Better still, replace all `"03 " and then the final `"03"`. Avoids problems such as `0303`.

Comment: OK shoot me now. Ended up deciding to write this script using bash. Should I start a new thread on that or can I get input on the same need in a bash script

Comment: @John, I had a asking question warning, 1 step close to question ban due to low response or downvote, It took me a lot of efforts to reverse it, my suggestion is to add bash tag to have this question closed, that mean you upvote and choose a accepted answer, and someone upvote for you